# Python CSV judge numbers' composition and replace it

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script to run PostgreSQL and store its output in a CSV file. The script and the file looks like,

```
import sys, os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop')
print os.getcwd()

#set up psycopg2 environment
import psycopg2

#driving_distance module
query = """
    select *
    from driving_distance ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            source::int4 as source,
            target::int4 as target,
            cost::double precision as cost,
            rcost::double precision as reverse_cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
"""

#make connection between python and postgresql
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'TC_area' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = 'xxxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()

#count rows in the table
cur.execute("select count(*) from network")
result = cur.fetchone()
k = result[0] + 1                #number of points = number of segments + 1

#run loops
rs = []
i = 1
while i <= k:
    cur.execute(query, (i, 100000000000, False, True))
    rs.append(cur.fetchall())
    i = i + 1

#import csv module
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil

j = 0
h = 0
ars = []
element = list(rs)

#export data to every row
filename = 'distMatrix.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    while j <= k - 1:
        while h <= k - 1:
            rp = element[j][h][2]
            ars.append(rp)
            h = h + 1
        else:
            h = 0
            writer.writerow(ars)
            ars = []
        j = j + 1

#concerning about flow-connection
with open(filename, 'rb') as f, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter = ',')
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        row = [element if float(element) < 10**6 else 0 for element in row]
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(g.name, filename)


conn.close()
```

[image]

The numbers in the CSV file are paths calculated by PostgreSQL, and I know they are all composed by the following numbers, let's call them **generator**

0, 1, 0.844, 0.69, 0.567, 0.387, 0.156, 0.31, 0.433, 0.613

I want to write some codes that can judge these 2 conditions, and then edit every field in this CSV file,

1. if numbers in the CSV file are just the same as one of the generator, then they stay the same as their original number
2. if numbers in the CSV file are not one of the generator, then the code can judge this number composed by what generator, **for example, 2 = 1 + 1**, and then change the **addition** to **multiplication**, for the last example, **replace this number by 1 * 1**

I think these additional codes should be implemented in this part of the script,

```
#export data to every row
filename = 'distMatrix.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    while j <= k - 1:
        while h <= k - 1:
            rp = element[j][h][2]
            ars.append(rp)
            h = h + 1
        else:
            h = 0
            writer.writerow(ars)
            ars = []
        j = j + 1
```

But how to do this task？ Please give me some suggestions and hints, thank you.

I am using python 2.7.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Am I a fool? I don't understand what you ask.

Comment: @mskimm I have edited my post, if still hard to understand, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: please provide an example of `input` and `output`.

Comment: Do you mean input of addition and output of multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your requirement is somewhat confusing.  But it sounds like to me you need a generator function to provide values on demand from a list and a way to test if the number is in a list...

```
list = [ 0, 1, 0.844, 0.69, 0.567, 0.387, 0.156, 0.31, 0.433, 0.613 ]

def gen():
    for i in range(len(list)):
        yield list[i]

g = gen()

def test_the_number(nbr):
    if nbr-int(nbr) in list:
        print("Number in list")
    else:
        print(next(g))

nbr = 5 # not in list
test_the_number(nbr)

nbr =777 # also not in the list
test_the_number(nbr)

nbr = 0.844  # In the list
test_the_number(nbr)
```